# <button> prevent 'space' click

Tags: jquery, html, events, button

I have a `<button>` which is activated by pressing the 'Space Bar', which I do not want, so I used `e.preventDefault();` which also disabled the 
'click' event, however the 'button' stays visually 'pressed'. Is there any fix? 
Using `e.stopPropagation();`  had no effect at all.

```js
$("#but").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
 });


$("#foo").click(function(){
 alert("Button stay 'pressed' until close the alert!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <button id="but">button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that your question is difficult to understand and so people will struggle to help you and your question is likely to be closed. If you could provide some code, ideally replicate the issue in jsFiddle or similar and clarify the issue it will help you get an answer.

Comment: Added some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style a button that has been 'clicked' to look like it hasn't, you can use `:active` in your css.
e.g.

`button:active {
 // reset the 'pressed' styles here.
}`